# How can we align an image and texts in same single line using google docs api with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

[image]I am working on google docs api with PHP code. I want to insert an image and texts in same line.Is it possible to do this with google docs api?
I can insert image and texts but not in single line.Is there any way to do so?

For inserting texts-

```
'insertText' => [
     'text' => "hello",
        'location' => [
        'index' => 1,
    ]
]
```

and for inserting images-

```
"insertInlineImage" => [
            "location" => [
                "index" => 1
            ],
            "uri" => "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/docs_64dp.png",
            "objectSize" => [
                "height"=> [
                    "magnitude"=> 10,
                    "unit" => "PT"
                ],
                "width"=> [
                    "magnitude"=> 10,
                    "unit"=> "PT"
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I noticed that your question had been updated. From your updated question, unfortunately, I thought that in the current stage, your goal cannot be directly achieved. So, in this updated answer, as a workaround, how about using a table as follows?

#### Sample script:

```php
$b = ["color" => ["color" => []], "dashStyle" => "SOLID", "width" => ["magnitude" => 0, "unit" => "PT"]];
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertTable' => [
            'location' => ['index' => 1],
            'columns' => 2,
            'rows' => 1
        ]
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        "updateTableCellStyle" => [
            "tableCellStyle" => [
                "borderBottom" => $b,
                "borderTop" => $b,
                "borderLeft" => $b,
                "borderRight" => $b,
            ],
            "tableStartLocation" => ["index" => 2],
            "fields" => "borderBottom,borderTop,borderLeft,borderRight"
        ]
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        "insertInlineImage" => [
        "location" => [
            "index" => 5
        ],
        "uri" => "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/docs_64dp.png",
        "objectSize" => [
            "height"=> [
                "magnitude"=> 100,
                "unit" => "PT"
            ],
            "width"=> [
                "magnitude"=> 100,
                "unit"=> "PT"
            ]
        ]
    ]]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => "hello1\nhello2\nhello3",
               'location' => [
               'index' => 8,
           ]
    ]]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        "updateParagraphStyle" => [
        "paragraphStyle" => [
            "alignment" => "START"
        ],
        "range" => [
            "startIndex" => 5,
            "endIndex" => 5,
        ],
        "fields" => "alignment"
    ]]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        "updateParagraphStyle" => [
        "paragraphStyle" => [
            "alignment" => "END"
        ],
        "range" => [
            "startIndex" => 8,
            "endIndex" => 23,
        ],
        "fields" => "alignment"
    ]]),
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array('requests' => $requests));
$responses = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

- When this script is run, a table of 1 row and 2 columns is created and the table border is removed. And, the image and text are put to the columns "A" and "B", respectively. And then, each cell is aligned.

#### Note:

- In this sample, I used a table of 1 row and 2 columns. If you want to modify this alignment, please modify the above script for your actual situation.

### Added:

From OP's following reply,

> But as you see in my picture I have shown it in my header and from your script what I have to change to make it on my header and for your information I am able to get my header id. Just help me to modify your answer to place that table and image in my header.

Unfortunately, I couldn't notice you wanted to put it to the header from your question and your showing script. In this case, a simple modification is reflected in the above script. Please add `segmentId` to each request as follows.

#### Sample script:

```php
$headerId = "kix.###"; // Please set your header ID.
$b = ["color" => ["color" => []], "dashStyle" => "SOLID", "width" => ["magnitude" => 0, "unit" => "PT"]];
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertTable' => [
            'location' => ['index' => 1, "segmentId" => $headerId],
            'columns' => 2,
            'rows' => 1
        ]
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        "updateTableCellStyle" => [
            "tableCellStyle" => [
                "borderBottom" => $b,
                "borderTop" => $b,
                "borderLeft" => $b,
                "borderRight" => $b,
            ],
            "tableStartLocation" => ["index" => 2, "segmentId" => $headerId],
            "fields" => "borderBottom,borderTop,borderLeft,borderRight"
        ]
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        "insertInlineImage" => [
        "location" => ["index" => 5, "segmentId" => $headerId],
        "uri" => "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/docs_64dp.png",
        "objectSize" => [
            "height"=> [
                "magnitude"=> 100,
                "unit" => "PT"
            ],
            "width"=> [
                "magnitude"=> 100,
                "unit"=> "PT"
            ]
        ]
    ]]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => "hello1\nhello2\nhello3",
               'location' => ['index' => 8, "segmentId" => $headerId]
    ]]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        "updateParagraphStyle" => [
        "paragraphStyle" => [
            "alignment" => "START"
        ],
        "range" => [
            "startIndex" => 5,
            "endIndex" => 5,
            "segmentId" => $headerId
        ],
        "fields" => "alignment"
    ]]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        "updateParagraphStyle" => [
        "paragraphStyle" => [
            "alignment" => "END"
        ],
        "range" => [
            "startIndex" => 8,
            "endIndex" => 23,
            "segmentId" => $headerId
        ],
        "fields" => "alignment"
    ]]),
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array('requests' => $requests));
$responses = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

#### Note:

- If you use the header ID of the 1st header ID, please check the checkbox for using the 1st header on the Google Document.

Comment: ,your script is correct but not that what I wanted. When we increase the size of image the texts goes on the end of the height of the image and I wanted it to be in side of that image basically I mean on same alignment, The image on the left and text on the right and there will be space in between them.I hope I able to explain my scenario.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice about `When we increase the size of image the texts goes on the end of the height of the image and I wanted it to be in side of that image basically I mean on same alignment, The image on the left and text on the right and there will be space in between them.`. Now, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: it did worked. Thankyou so much for your help. But as you see in my picture I have shown it in my header and from your script what I have to change to make it on my header and for your information I am able to get my header id. Just help me to modify your answer to place that table and image in my header.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. About `But as you see in my picture I have shown it in my header`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice it from your updated question and your provided script. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. About `But as you see in my picture I have shown it in my header`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice it from your updated question and your provided script. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I already did it like this and it did worked.Thanks.